# How to properly package flask application with static files

Tags: python, flask, packaging

I'm trying to create a python package for a webapp (flask based) and I'd like to get some files installed in a known directory.

For example flask tries to find the `templates` and `static` directories inside the current package when running the integrated server (paste-based). But in production I'd rather like those directories installed in a more specific place like `virtualenv/share/package-name/{static,templates}`. Otherwise they would be somewhere under `lib/python-2.x/...` which doesn't seem appropriate.

I tried to install the files using the `data_files` parameter in `setup.py`, but that doesn't seem to be useful for whole trees (`error: can't copy 'xxx': doesn't exist or not a regular file`).

What's the proper solution in this situation?

Comment: This helped me a lot with packaging my Flask app: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/distribute/#basic-setup-script

Comment: I've seen it. Unfortunately they just copy the package along with data files. I'm doing it now, but I'd really like to stop. I just really don't like pointing my webserver at `/home/xxx_webapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xxx-1.0dev-py2.7.egg/xxx/static/`. I'd rather use something like `/home/xxx_webapp/venv/share/xxx/static/`

Comment: Why are you trying to serve the static files with something else than the functionality flask provides?

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer Because nginx can handle the static file on its own without involving the python code. That means most of the requests don't have to block the dynamic part of your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is package up your virtual env and static files into a native package (.deb or .rpm) and then you could place these anywhere you want. I wrote a blog post on this [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160214035604/http://www.plankandwhittle.com/packaging-a-flask-app-in-a-debian-package/). It uses a handy little ruby gem called [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) and although I dont seperate my static files from my python package you would be able to by adding another path mapping on the end of the fpm command like so

```
    fpm -s dir -t deb -n food-truck -v 0.1 -d "python,python-dev,postgresql" /home/ubuntu/food_truck-build/=/home/ubuntu/foodtruck.com <path to static files>=<destination of static files>
```

You could use fpm to specify other config files such as your nginx config etc as well. But thats up to you, and might mean your deployment is a little less flexible.

Hope that helps!